How to create a dynamic link with variables in block schema?
I'm trying to create a link to the app settings within a Shopify block using schema in Liquid. I want to include dynamic variables like shop.domain and block.id in the URL.
Here’s my code:
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "block",
    "target": "body",
    "settings": [
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "Customize [App Configuration Page](https://admin.shopify.com/store/{{ shop.domain }}/apps/myapp/{{ block.id }})"
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}

However, the variables {{ shop.domain }} and {{ block.id }} are not being parsed within the schema. The link displays as plain text rather than dynamically replacing these variables.
Is there a way to include dynamic variables in the link within the Shopify block schema? If not, are there any recommended workarounds for creating dynamic links in Shopify blocks?
UPDATE 1
Thanks for reply - but this button is visible at front public page ...
and i see  in this app - they create link to app - so shop url is dynamic variable . Hot they do it ?

You can not directly include dynamic variables in URLs within the Shopify schema, you can work around this limitation by using a combination of block settings and Liquid templating outside the schema.
First, define a block setting for a part of the URL:
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Custom Block",
    "settings": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "url_part",
            "label": "URL Part",
            "default": "myapp"
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}

Then,
{% if block.settings.url_part %}
   <a href="https://admin.shopify.com/store/{{ shop.domain }}/apps/{{ block.settings.url_part }}/{{ block.id }}">App Configuration Page</a>
 {% endif %}


possible to add this link only in theme editor ?

You need to use the type liquid in the schema.
    {
      "type": "liquid",
      "id": "d_link",
      "label": "Dynamic Link"
    },

Then in the customizer you can add the liquid code into the block.
https://admin.shopify.com/store/{{ shop.domain }}/apps/myapp/

And when you get the variable into the code you need to append the block.id.
{{ block.settings.d_link | append: block.id }}

Then you get the dynamic link like below example:
https://admin.shopify.com/store/your-store.myshopify.com/apps/myapp/buttons_XF8RPK

